# Nvidia Driver Issue on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am trying to install some drivers on my new laptop (Dell xps 5). 
This is my current ubuntu version:

[image]

This is my current driver:

[image]

and when I changed into one of the nvidia drivers, I get this when I restart my laptop:
[image]

And I am stuck there I cannot pressed the OK button, even if its there. So I power off  my laptop and start it again and choose one of the `generic` modes
to start Ubuntu again. Is there an application or smth which search and install your drivers for Ubuntu, like SlimDriver for Windows  ?   Or do you other idea how to fix this ? Thank you!

[`UPDATE`]

After I installed the Intel Graphics I tried to install one of the nvidia drivers and I get this when I restarted my laptop:
[image]

But this issue was fixed: [Fast-pressed key triggers auto-repeat (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567269/fast-pressed-key-triggers-auto-repeat-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Comment: I did , but   after `Step5. Reboot your computer for the new driver to kick-in. You can check your installation status with the following command` I get stuck with the third image that I attached :)

Comment: Found this https://www.cilicia.us/wp/?p=1612 If that works I'll add it as the Answer.

Comment: The Page above has this tool for Intel Graphics. https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main/pool/main/i/intel-graphics-update-tool/intel-graphics-update-tool_2.0.2_amd64.deb

Comment: I will try it this evening. Thnx , I'll let u know tomorrow :)

Comment: hey @EODCraftStaff see my update in the post . thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it will help someone. In the end I manage to install nvidia drivers:

I went to the `addition drivers` and select a nvidia driver then I went to:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

and I made sure that I have this lines:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi=force" 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi=force"
```

I had the `acpi` set to `off`. I have no idea why :) It was a random guess to put it to `force` and It fixed my problem that i described in the question. Maybe someone will give a proper explanation for this .

Comment: I still don't understand Nvidia graphics on Intel...Oh well, as long as it works I guess :)